# How would I add the tts output of this code into Nvidia auidio2face?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, nvidia, speech-to-text

In this code:

```
import json
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

class UserProfile:
    def __init__(self, name, age, interests):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.interests = interests

    def to_dict(self):
        return {"name": self.name, "age": self.age, "interests": self.interests}

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data):
        return cls(data["name"], data["age"], data["interests"])

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}, Age: {self.age}, Interests: {self.interests}"

class ProfileManager:
    def __init__(self, device_index):
        self.profiles = []
        self.tts_engine = pyttsx3.init()
        self.recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        self.device_index = device_index

        self.adjust_ambient_noise

    def adjust_ambient_noise(self):
        with sr.Microphone(device_index=self.device_index) as source:
            print("Adjusting for ambient noise. Please wait...")
            self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)

    def create_profile(self):
        self.tts_speak("Please say your name.")
        name = self.get_voice_input()

        self.tts_speak("Please say your age.")
        age = int(self.get_voice_input())

        self.tts_speak("Please say your interests.")
        interests = self.get_voice_input()

        profile = UserProfile(name, age, interests)
        self.profiles.append(profile)
        self.save_profiles()
        self.tts_speak(f"Profile created for {name}.")

    def list_profiles(self):
        if not self.profiles:
            self.tts_speak("No profiles available.")
        else:
            for profile in self.profiles:
                self.tts_speak(str(profile))
 
    def tts_speak(self, text):
        try:
            self.tts_engine.say(text)
            self.tts_engine.runAndWait()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error during TTS: {e}")

    def get_voice_input(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening....")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
          print("Recognizing....")
          query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
          print(f"user said: {query}\n")
        except Exception as e:
          print(e)
          return "None"
        return query
        
    def process_voice_input(self):
        spoken_text = self.get_voice_input()

        if "create" in spoken_text:
            self.create_profile()
        elif "list" in spoken_text:
            self.list_profiles()
        elif "exit" in spoken_text:
            self.save_profiles()  # Save profiles before exiting
            self.tts_speak("Exiting program. Goodbye!")
            exit()
        else:
            self.tts_speak("Invalid command. Please try again.")

    def save_profiles(self):
        with open("profiles4.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump([profile.to_dict() for profile in self.profiles], file)

    def load_profiles(self):
        try:
            with open("profiles4.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                self.profiles = [UserProfile.from_dict(profile_data) for profile_data in data]
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass  # Ignore if the file is not found

# Interactive usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    device_index = 45
    manager = ProfileManager(device_index=device_index)
    manager.load_profiles()  # Load existing profiles when the program starts


    while True:
        manager.process_voice_input()
```

It runs a simple program that takes a text input and profiles the user. It can then draw this profile for later use. I would like to implement the TTS output given by pyttsx3 with Nvidia Audio2Face, how would I do this? (Also if my code is really dirty it would be great if you could give pointers. Im learning right now, and using some chatgpt tutorials..)

error given after fixing call:

```
Adjusting for ambient noise. Please wait...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grump\Desktop\testingmemory\memory4.py", line 33, in adjust_ambient_noise
    self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)
  File "C:\Users\grump\miniforge3\envs\assistant\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 383, in adjust_for_ambient_noise
    assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before adjusting, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grump\Desktop\testingmemory\memory4.py", line 108, in <module>
    manager = ProfileManager(device_index=device_index)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\grump\Desktop\testingmemory\memory4.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.adjust_ambient_noise()
  File "C:\Users\grump\Desktop\testingmemory\memory4.py", line 31, in adjust_ambient_noise
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=self.device_index) as source:
  File "C:\Users\grump\miniforge3\envs\assistant\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 189, in __exit__
    self.stream.close()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, you can implement `from_dict` as `return cls(**data)`.

Comment: Feeding the audio file in is probably the least complicated part of Audio2Face.  Have you worked through the manual and the samples?  It's also important to remember that computer-generated speech is not going to have any emotion.  Also, you're missing `()` from your `adjust_ambient_noise` call.

Comment: That makes sense. It just wasn't running. I do know how to use audio2face, I just don't know how to combine this code with that program. Also, what would I use return cls for? (how would I implement it?) check edit for new error)

Comment: I don't believe you "combine" the two.  Your program will produce an audio file, which you then import into audio2face.  Are you sure the device_index you're using is correct?  Have you enumerated the microphones to make sure?

Comment: Yes, the microphone is correct and even without the adjust_ambient_noise call it seems to work perfectly. However, I am not sure how to export the audio file or how to stream it to audio2face. (also, I am not sure how I would make an edit function that allows me to edit a profile after creating it.)

Comment: What audio file are you expecting to capture?  You're reading snippets from the microphone and doing text recognition, and you're feeding strings to text-to-speech.

Comment: I am capturing output.wav